# Count occurrences of a list of words in a text file

Tags: bash

I have two text files, File1 looks like this:

```
apple
dog
cat
..
..
```

and File2 looks like this:

```
appledogtree 
dog
catapple
apple00001
..
..
```

I want to count the occurrences of the list of words from File1 in File2, and get a result like below:

(words in File1, number of occurrences in File2)

```
apple 3
dog 2
cat 1
```

How can I do this by using Bash command line?

Comment: This isn't a programming problem/Q. But `man grep` should be able to help you. In the future, please use the `{}` format tool at the top left of the edit box on highlighted text to format as code/data/output. Good luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `fgrep` to do this efficiently:

```
fgrep -of f1.txt f2.txt | sort | uniq -c | awk '{print $2 " " $1}'
```

Gives this output:

```
apple 3
cat 1
dog 2
```

- `fgrep -of f1.txt f2.txt` extracts all the matching parts (`-o` option) of f2.txt based on the patterns in f1.txt
- `sort | uniq -c` counts the matching patterns
- finally, `awk` swaps the order of words in `uniq -c` output

Comment: Given that same input files as I have in my answer, `fgrep` does not get `cat`

Comment: It did for me.  Please check your files again.

Comment: There should be no reason why `fgrep` would treat a particular string differently unless you called it with `-w` flag.

Comment: The reason is POSIX grep treats file input differently than GNU grep. POSIX grep produces this output if one uses `grep -Eo "apple|dog|cat" f2.txt` but not with a file input of patterns. GNU grep has the same output in both cases.

Answer (score 3):

Given:

```
$ cat f1.txt
apple
dog
cat
$ cat f2.txt
appledogtree 
dog
catapple
apple00001
```

Try:

```
while IFS= read -r line || [[ -n $line ]]; do 
    printf "%s->%s\n" $line "$(grep -c $line f2.txt)"
done <f1.txt
```

Prints:

```
apple->3
dog->2
cat->1
```

---

If you want a pipeline, you can do:

```
cat f1.txt | xargs | sed -e 's/ /\|/g' | grep -Eof /dev/stdin f2.txt | awk '{a[$1]++} END{for (x in a) print x, a[x]}'
```

Which does:

1. `cat f1.txt` puts the contents of the file to stdin;
2. `xargs` translates that to one line;
3. `sed -e 's/ /\|/g'` joins the words into `"apple|dog|cat"`;
4. `grep -Eof /dev/stdin f2.txt` uses that pattern to print the matches of the pattern;
5. `awk '{a[$1]++} END{for (x in a) print x, a[x]}'` counts the words and prints the count.

With GNU grep, you can do `grep -Eof - f2.txt`

That pipeline works on POSIX and Linux...

---

If you want *pure efficiency* just use awk:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {pat[FNR]=$1; next} 
             {for (i in pat){ if(match($0, pat[i])){m[pat[i]]++}}} 
             END{for(e in m){print e,m[e]}}'  f1.txt f2.txt
```

Comment: This can be quite costly if f1.txt is large.

Answer (score 1):

In awk:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR { a[$1]; next }                  # read in all search words
               { for(i in a) a[i]+=gsub(i,i) }  # count matches of all keywords in record
            END{ for(i in a) print i,a[i] }     # output results
' file1 file2
apple 3
cat 1
dog 2
```