# awk Print Line Issue

Tags: linux, macos, awk

I'm experiencing some issues with a `awk` command right now. The original script was developed using `awk` on MacOS and was then ported to Linux. There `awk` shows a different behavior.

What I want to do is to count the occurrences of single strings provided via `/tmp/test.uniq.txt` in the file `/tmp/test.txt`.

```
awk '{print $1, system("cat /tmp/test.txt | grep -o -c " $1)}' /tmp/test.uniq.txt
```

Mac delivers an expected output like:

```
  test1 2 
  test2 1
```

The output is in one line, the sting and the number of occurrences,  separated by a whitespace.

Linux delivers an output like:

```
2
test1 1
test2
```

The output is not in one line an the output of the system command is printed first.

Sample input: 
test.txt looks like:

```
test1 test test 
test1 test test
test2 test test
```

test.uniq.txt looks like:

```
test1
test2
```

Comment: Good that you have shown the code which you are using, you have to show us the sample of input since you need not to use `grep` etc on `awk` if we could see input sample here.

Comment: Using `cat/grep` inside an `awk` is anti-pattern at best. `Awk` is powerful in itself in doing the processing you need. Post a proper input and expected output to get better solutions

Comment: I agree, but that was the only solution I found to have the string with the number of occurrences.

Comment: @david: Whats your expected output the for the input given

Comment: @david: What if you have `test123` in `test.txt`. Should that match `test1` or not?

Comment: Linux usually has [GNU Awk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/), whereas macOS's is derived from FreeBSD, whose awk I believe comes from the [One True Awk](https://github.com/onetrueawk/awk). Output difference may be due to buffering. Gawk shows the `system()` output first, with the output from the awk script itself after the commands for that line (including `system()` are all run. Not sure what you're seeing from macOS, it's not what I would expect for that input.

Comment: What is tha `5` in your output supposed to represent? I can't get anywhere close to replicating your output given the input you've provided. Your code *appears* to be trying to show a line count from `test.txt` for each entry in the `uniq` file. Is that it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count occurrences of a list of words in a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41928918/count-occurrences-of-a-list-of-words-in-a-text-file)

Comment: Sry the output did not match the the sample data. Fixed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As comments suggested that using `grep` and `cat` etc using `system` function is not recommended as `awk` is complete language that can perform most of these tasks.

You can use following `awk` command to replace your `cat | grep` functionality:

```
awk 'FNR == NR {a[$1]=0; next} {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i in a) a[$i]++} 
END { for (i in a) print i, a[i] }' uniq.txt test.txt
```

```
test1 2
test2 1
```

Note that this output doesn't match with the count `5` as your question states as your sample data is probably different.

---

**References:**

- [Effective AWK Programming](https://www.gnu.org/s/gawk/manual/gawk.pdf)
- [Awk Tutorial](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html)

Comment: Yes the count of 5 was related to my old sample data. Thx for your solution.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me as if you're trying to count the number of line containing each unique string in the `uniq` file.  But the way you're doing it is .. awkward, and as you've demonstrated, inconsistent between versions of awk.

The following might work a little better:

```
$ awk '
  NR==FNR {
    a[$1]
    next
  }
  {
    for (i in a) {
      if ($1~i) {
        a[i]++
      }
    }
  }
  END {
    for (i in a)
      printf "%6d\t%s\n",a[i],i
  }
' test.uniq.txt test.txt
         2  test1
         1  test2
```

This loads your `uniq` file into an array, then for every line in your text file, steps through the array to count the matches.

Note that these are being compared as regular expressions, without word boundaries, so `test1` will also be counted as part of `test12`.

Answer (score 0):

Another way might be to use `grep`+`sort`+`uniq`:

```
grep -o -w -F -f uniq.txt test.txt | sort | uniq -c
```

It's a pipeline but a short one

From `man grep`:

> - `-F`, `--fixed-strings`, `--fixed-regexp` Interpret  PATTERN  as a list of fixed strings, separated by newlines, any of which is to be matched.
>               (`-F` is specified by POSIX, `--fixed-regexp` is an obsoleted alias, please do not use it in new scripts.)
> - `-f FILE`, `--file=FILE` Obtain patterns from FILE, one per line.  The empty file contains zero patterns and therefore matches nothing.  (`-f` is specified by POSIX.)
> - `-o`, `--only-matching` Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line, with each such part on a separate output line.
> - `-w`, `--word-regexp`
>               Select only those lines containing matches that form whole words.  The test is that the matching substring must either be at the beginning of the line or preceded by a non-word constituent character. Similarly, it must be either at the end of the line or followed by a non-word constituent character. Word-constituent characters are letters, digits, and the underscore.